# Finding the least number of terms to satisfy integer square equation

Tags: haskell

The following code is a solution to [an exercise I've made](https://github.com/exercism/problem-specifications/issues/1570):

> This exercise idea is based on a story from my current work place: My boss'es Ubuntu had a bug that made his printer, when asked to print *N* copies of something, instead print *N²* copies. So for our Thursday status meeting, he'd hope that the number of people who show up, for whom he would bring a copy of his status report, was targetable with as few print requests as possible.
>
> For example, if 13 people would show up to the meeting, he would first ask the printer of 3 copies (yielding 9 copies), and then 2 copies (yielding 4 copies) copies, with a final result of 3² + 2² = 13 copies. For some numbers of employees, this was simply not possible with two print jobs, and he'd need to consult the printer a third time.
>
> The exercise is to write a function that computes the *groan factor*, being the minimal number of print jobs it takes to print *N* copies of a status report when the printer gives you back *N²* copies.
>
> Examples:
>
> - It takes 1 print job to print 1 copy because 1² = 1.
> - It takes 2 print jobs to print 5 copies because 2² + 1² = 5.
> - It takes 3 print jobs to print 11 copies because 3² + 1² + 1² = 11.
>
> The suggested exercise name comes from the thought that it must be kafkaesque to hope that a specific number of employees *N* show up on Thursdays such that ∃ *a*, *b* ∈ ℕ₀: *a*² + *b*² = *N*.

For more background information, see [Lagrange's four-square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem).

I am unsure how to improve on my solution below, but among the things I am dissatisfied with are: (1) the repetitiveness inside `hasTwo` and `hasThree`, and (2) the use of `elemOrd` seems a little non-standard, and (3) the constant use of `(^ 2)` throws a bunch of warnings about `2` defaulting to `Integer` when I'm really just using `Int` here.

Any feedback to the solution below is appreciated.

**Refactored 1:**

- Instead of having `hasOne, hasTwo, hasThree :: Int -> Bool` as top-level definitions, I've introduced a type class `SquarePolynomial` and wrote a  `hasSquare :: SquarePolynomial a => Int -> [a] -> Bool`.
- This eliminates any specialized solutions: for *P = 1* I can find a solution in constant time, for *P = 2* I can find a solution by prime factorization, and for *P = 3* the straight-forward solution using integer modulo that @vnp suggests in a comment.
- Because there are three algorithms for different `n`, this is a bad choice, but I like that the code has one generalised solution strategy, even though it's not the best one in each case. An optimal strategy might first check 1, then 3, then 2, then go with 4.
- Since I cannot easily generate the list sorted by `value`, i.e. (2,2) comes before (3,1), which is good because *2² + 2² = 8* and *3² + 1² = 10*, but (3,3) also comes before (4,1), which is bad because *3² + 3² = 18* and *4² + 1² = 17*. So I can't assume that `map value` is monotonically increasing. E.g. to find `hasSquare 17 twoTerms` I end up generating

  ```
    takeWhile ((isqrt n >=) . maxTerm) twoTerms
  = takeWhile ((4 >=) . maxTerm) twoTerms
  = takeWhile ((4 >=) . maxTerm) [(1,1),(2,1),...]
  = [(1,1),(2,1),(2,2),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(4,1),(4,2),(4,3),(4,4)]
  ```

  to avoid stopping at `value (3,3)` being 18 when `value (4,1)` is 17.

The code after refactoring (see edit history for previous version):

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
module KafkaPrinter (groanFactor) where

groanFactor :: Int -> Int
groanFactor 0 = 0
groanFactor n
  | n `isSquareWith` oneTerm = 1
  | n `isSquareWith` twoTerms = 2  --  http://oeis.org/A000404
  | n `isSquareWith` threeTerms = 3  --  https://oeis.org/A000408
  | otherwise = 4

-- Find if any candidate polynomial 'a^2 + b^2 + ...' of nonzero squares
-- exists such that 'a^2 + b^2 + ... = n'. Assume that candidates are
-- ordered by their largest term, 'maxTerm', and limit candidates so that
-- 'maxTerm <= isqrt n'.
--
-- This is an upper bound because
--  ⇒ maxTerm^2 + K <= n
--  ⇒ maxTerm <= isqrt (n - K)
--  ⇒ maxTerm <= isqrt n
isSquareWith :: SquarePolynomial a => Int -> [a] -> Bool
isSquareWith n = elem n . map value . takeWhile ((isqrt n >=) . maxTerm)

square :: Num a => a -> a
square = (^ (2 :: Int))

isqrt :: Int -> Int
isqrt = floor @Float . sqrt . fromIntegral

class SquarePolynomial a where
  value :: a -> Int
  maxTerm :: a -> Int

instance SquarePolynomial Int where
  value = square
  maxTerm = id

oneTerm :: [Int]
oneTerm = [1..]

instance SquarePolynomial (Int, Int) where
  value (i, j) = square i + square j
  maxTerm (i, _) = i

-- [(1,1), (2,1), (2,2), (3,1), ...]
twoTerms :: [(Int, Int)]
twoTerms = iterate next (1,1)
  where next (i, j) = if i > j then (i, j+1) else (i+1, 1)

instance SquarePolynomial (Int, Int, Int) where
  value (i, j, k) = square i + square j + square k
  maxTerm (i, _, _) = i

-- [(1,1,1), (2,1,1), (2,2,1), (2,2,2), (3,1,1), ...]
threeTerms :: [(Int, Int, Int)]
threeTerms = iterate next (1,1,1)
  where
    next (i, j, k)
      | j > k     = (i, j, k+1)
      | i > j     = (i, j+1, 1)
      | otherwise = (i+1, 1, 1)
```

The end.

Comment: You may be also interested in [Legendre's three-square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem) and [Fermat's two-square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem) theorems. At least the first one simplifies `hasThree` in a very straightforward way.